# Dynamical systems: Is there always an attractor?

Tags: dynamical-systems

I am just starting out with dynamical systems, and I am wondering if you can have a dynamical system with out any attractors (if so, can you give an example).

Explanations or references backing up answers are appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean http://www.math.psu.edu/tseng/class/Math251/Notes-PhasePlane.pdf? maybe you meant $x' = ...$ instead?

Comment: $$x'_1=x'_2=\cdots=x'_n=1$$

Comment: Are examples in $\mathbb{R}^n$ enough for you or maybe you want something more compact? :)

Comment: Have you tried finding one? What have you tried? What is your definition for "attractior"?

Comment: See also the [Poincaré–Bendixson theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Bendixson_theorem).

Answer (score 5):

There are several systems that don't have any attractors. E.g. all unstable systems are without attractors, as illustrated by 
$$x_1' = −2 x_1 − 6 x_2 + 8, \; x_2' = 8 x_1 + 4x_2 − 12,$$ as shown in on page 19 of [this note](http://www.math.psu.edu/tseng/class/Math251/Notes-PhasePlane.pdf) (provided by Moo in a comment)

[image]